# Trying to relate 2 Entries together

Tags: entries

I have two channels, Courses and Instructors. In Courses I'd like to have a an entries field called "Instructor" so that this will display on the courses page.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I have found a few tutes but nothing I have tried has worked. Whats the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything you need to know is in the [Relations](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations) part of the official documentation.

You essentially want to add an [Entries](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields) field to your `Courses` channel and then when you set it up pick `Instructors` as the source. If you only want to pick one instructor, just set the `limit` to 1. How you then use this in the templates can be found [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/entries-fields#templating).

Comment: So I've tried using the code `{% for entry in entry.instructor %} ... {% endfor %}` but all I get is a 500 Fatal error. I was using the documentation before but as I mentioned above I can't seem to figure out the precise code that would get it to work and the documentation has so much assumed knowledge that I can't figure it out.

Comment: I've tried many other variations like `{% for instructors in courses.instructor %} ... {% endfor %}` but none seem to work. To me that code is exactly like the example `{% for ingredient in cocktail.ingredients %}
            <li>{{ ingredient.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}` but it doesn't work and I really don't understand why...

Comment: So the winner is `{% for instructors in entry.instructor %}` I found that also there was come other code from when the instructor field was just a text field that was causing issues. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted in the end. It's because you can have one or many in your relationship so an array is returned. I don't know how many instructors you are assigning to each course, but if there was only ever one you could use `{% set instructor = entry.instructor.first() %}` which would bring you back just the one, or `null` (I think) if you haven't yet assigned one.